Docker compose multiple Etherpad with apache frontal
I have a problem with a service built with a docker compose, I don't understand what's wrong.
I have a Debian server on which I want to host 3 instances of Etherpad, each with its own configuration. In addition to the 3 Etherpads, I want apache on the front end to allow access to the Etherpad instances via https.
At the moment, my system is only partially working. The docker compose launches without a hitch, the 3 Etherpads are accessible via their ports and I can create pads:

http://etherpad.mydomain.com:9001 (etherpad libre)
http://etherpad.mydomain.com:9002 (etherpad moodle)
http://etherpad.mydomain.com:9003 (etherpad redmine)

So I've configured apache2 to do reverse proxy:

https://etherpad.mydomain.com/libre/ (etherpad libre)
https://etherpad.mydomain.com/moodle/ (etherpad moodle)
https://etherpad.mydomain.com/redmine/ (etherpad redmine)

No problems with the reverse proxy to the first pad (etherpad libre), it works and I can create pads.
However, the other two don't work, I get the error :
Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. 

And on the apache2 front-end logs I get this error :
[Wed Jul 24 13:54:38.027789 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 22:tid 25] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9002 (127.0.0.1:9002) failed
[Wed Jul 24 13:54:38.027895 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 22:tid 25] [client 10.26.24.52:52664] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1

I can't figure out why. Any clue is welcome ?!
Here is the docker compose :
x-proxy-args: &proxy-args
  HTTP_PROXY: http://proxy.mydomaine.com:3333
  HTTPS_PROXY: http://proxy.mydomaine.com:3333
  no_proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1

x-ether-args: &ether-args
  INSTALL_SOFFICE: true
  ETHERPAD_PLUGINS: ep_adminpads2 ep_align ep_author_hover ep_font_color ep_font_family ep_font_size ep_headings2 ep_remove_embed ep_set_title_on_pad ep_special_characters ep_subscript_and_superscript ep_table_of_contents

services:
  etherpad-libre:
    image: etherpad-libre
    build:
      context: ./etherpad-lite
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: ${HTTP_PROXY}
        HTTPS_PROXY: ${HTTPS_PROXY}
        no_proxy: ${no_proxy}
        INSTALL_SOFFICE: ${INSTALL_SOFFICE}
        ETHERPAD_PLUGINS: ${ETHERPAD_PLUGINS}
    networks:
      - etherpad
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./etherpad-config/libre-settings.json:/opt/etherpad-lite/settings.json
      - ./etherpad-config/libre-credentials.json:/opt/etherpad-lite/credentials.json
  etherpad-moodle:
    image: etherpad-moodle
    build:
      context: ./etherpad-lite
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: ${HTTP_PROXY}
        HTTPS_PROXY: ${HTTPS_PROXY}
        no_proxy: ${no_proxy}
        INSTALL_SOFFICE: ${INSTALL_SOFFICE}
        ETHERPAD_PLUGINS: ${ETHERPAD_PLUGINS}
    networks:
      - etherpad
    ports:
      - "9002:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./etherpad-config/moodle-settings.json:/opt/etherpad-lite/settings.json
      - ./etherpad-config/moodle-credentials.json:/opt/etherpad-lite/credentials.json
  etherpad-redmine:
    image: etherpad-redmine
    build:
      context: ./etherpad-lite
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: ${HTTP_PROXY}
        HTTPS_PROXY: ${HTTPS_PROXY}
        no_proxy: ${no_proxy}
        INSTALL_SOFFICE: ${INSTALL_SOFFICE}
        ETHERPAD_PLUGINS: ${ETHERPAD_PLUGINS}
    networks:
      - etherpad
    ports:
      - "9003:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./etherpad-config/redmine-settings.json:/opt/etherpad-lite/settings.json
      - ./etherpad-config/redmine-credentials.json:/opt/etherpad-lite/credentials.json
  apache2-frontal:
    image: apache2-frontal
    build:
      context: ./apache2-frontal
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: ${HTTP_PROXY}
        HTTPS_PROXY: ${HTTPS_PROXY}
        no_proxy: ${no_proxy}
    networks:
      - etherpad
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com:/etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com
networks:
  etherpad:
    driver: bridge

And here is the apache2 configuration :
# préconisations RSSI
ServerTokens Prod

# global servername
ServerName etherpad.mydomaine.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName etherpad.mydomaine.com
    Redirect permanent / https://etherpad.mydomaine.com/libre/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName etherpad.mydomaine.com

    # logs
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # SSL
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com/fullchain.pem

    # préconisations RSSI
    ServerSignature Off
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <Directory />
            Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
            Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
            Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    # redirection / vers l'Etherpad libre
    Redirect permanent / https://etherpad.mydomaine.com/libre/

    # Etherpad réécritures
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/libre/socket.io/(.*) ws://etherpad-libre:9001/socket.io/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^/moodle/socket.io/(.*) ws://etherpad-moodle:9002/socket.io/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^/redmine/socket.io/(.*) ws://etherpad-redmine:9003/socket.io/$1 [P,L]

    # Etherpad proxypass
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /libre/ http://etherpad-libre:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse /libre/ http://etherpad-libre:9001/
    ProxyPass /moodle/ http://etherpad-moodle:9002/
    ProxyPassReverse /moodle/ http://etherpad-moodle:9002/
    ProxyPass /redmine/ http://etherpad-redmine:9003/
    ProxyPassReverse /redmine/ http://etherpad-redmine:9003/
    <Proxy *>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>


I tried to replace apache2 by nginx, it seems the result is the same, nginx give "502 Bad Gateway" on the 2 other Etherpad.

Thanks for the -1 without comment ...

OK, that was obvious, looking at iptables made me think straight away. If the containers each have their own ports, apache accesses the container's port directly, so 9001. For the two services that don't work, you need to call their real port 9001 in the apache configuration and that solves the problem.
# préconisations RSSI
ServerTokens Prod

# global servername
ServerName etherpad.mydomaine.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName etherpad.mydomaine.com
    Redirect permanent / https://etherpad.mydomaine.com/libre/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName etherpad.mydomaine.com

    # logs
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # SSL
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/certificats/etherpad.mydomaine.com/fullchain.pem

    # préconisations RSSI
    ServerSignature Off
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <Directory />
            Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
            Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
            Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    # redirection / vers l'Etherpad libre
    Redirect permanent / https://etherpad.mydomaine.com/libre/

    # Etherpad réécritures
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/libre/socket.io/(.*) ws://etherpad-libre:9001/socket.io/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^/moodle/socket.io/(.*) ws://etherpad-moodle:9001/socket.io/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^/redmine/socket.io/(.*) ws://etherpad-redmine:9001/socket.io/$1 [P,L]

    # Etherpad proxypass
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /libre/ http://etherpad-libre:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse /libre/ http://etherpad-libre:9001/
    ProxyPass /moodle/ http://etherpad-moodle:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse /moodle/ http://etherpad-moodle:9001/
    ProxyPass /redmine/ http://etherpad-redmine:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse /redmine/ http://etherpad-redmine:9001/
    <Proxy *>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>

